# OpenQuery in Power BI giving me back an error

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, openquery

I am new to Stored procedures & OpenQuery in Power BI.

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server database by passing an SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ([DVT-FUSION],
'EXEC CRM_DVT.dbo.SP_RPT_Billing_Summary ''R1'', ''R2'', ''0'', ''0''  ')
```

But for some reason I get back an error stating:

> Microsoft SQL: Server 'DVT-FUSION' is not configured for DATA ACCESS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggested, you database is not configured for `DATA ACCESS`.

You should run this once on your SQL Server instance:

```
EXEC sp_serveroption 'DVT-FUSION', 'DATA ACCESS', 'true';
```

Comment: Thanks @FoxanNg, it worked. I would like to know how can I get the date as a field to filter my report?

Comment: @Rush Can you accept this answer as correct and ask the new question in a separate question with more details?

Comment: Sure, I will post a new question if I cannot resolve it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Rush Please mark this answer as accepted as shown [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) if it helps solving your issue. Thanks!